# How do I programmatically get a list of locked files under a folder structure?

Tags: c#, windows, file, windows-server-2003

Following up from this question: [How can I unlock a file that is locked by a process in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242882/how-can-i-unlock-a-file-that-is-locked-by-a-process-in-net), how do I programmatically get a list of files that are locked in a particular folder and its subfolders?

I'm using Windows 2003, .NET 3.5, C# 3.0.

**Update:** some background... basically we're archiving closed websites on a shared server. After deleting the site from IIS we move the folder structure for the site to an archive where it's held for 6 weeks. Even though the IIS site and FTP has been stopped and deleted we still encounter locked files during the move. So it'd be nice to know upfront what's still got a lock on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in another question :[How to check for file lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/checking-for-file-lock-in-c)

The only way would be trying them all and add them to the list if it throws an exception.
As mentioned in the above question, it would not be a reliable list to use, but only give you an overview of a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to detect locked files in real time would be to write a device driver (like [filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)), but I don't think you can do that in C#.