# File permission

Tags: c#

If by some program fault a file is locked, is there any way to remove that lock. 
please explain how file unlocking software works. Looking forward for ideas

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242882/how-can-i-unlock-a-file-that-is-locked-by-a-process-in-net.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offers a program called [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which can display help you figure out which program has a particular file or directory open. This may be the solution to the problem you're talking about, if some process that you're unaware of is accessing the file and preventing other access to it.