# How to delete file temp.jpg with process A if locked by process B

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, temporary-files, file-locking

how File.Delete() file temp.jpg with process A if locked by process B. **how close handles file temp.jpg**

**IOExceoption:
The process cannot access the file Because it is being used by another process**

```
protected void ButtonJcrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    String tempPath = Server.MapPath("..") + @"\Users\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + @"\temp.gif";


    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempPath);
    Bitmap bmpCropped = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCropped);
    Rectangle rectDestination = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpCropped.Width, bmpCropped.Height);
    Rectangle rectCropArea = new Rectangle(Int32.Parse(hfX.Value), Int32.Parse(hfY.Value), Int32.Parse(hfWidth.Value), Int32.Parse(hfHeight.Value));
    g.DrawImage(img, rectDestination, rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    String mapPath = @"\Users\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + @"\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + ".gif";
    bmpCropped.Save(Server.MapPath("..") + mapPath);
    // bmpCropped.Save(Server.MapPath("..") + @"\Images\thumbs\CroppedImages\" + Session["WorkingImage"]);
    imCropped.ImageUrl = Request.ApplicationPath + mapPath;
    **File.Delete(tempPath);**

    PlaceHolderImCropped.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I unlock a file that is locked by a process in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242882/how-can-i-unlock-a-file-that-is-locked-by-a-process-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

Wait for process B to release the resource.

**Pro-tip:**
Process B locked the file for a reason.  Stealing it is a bad idea in any situation I can think of that isn't pathological.

If you're in a pathological situation:

1. Get out of the pathological situation.  You're only digging
   yourself in deeper.
2. Kill process B.

Are there other techniques?  Yes.  They are by definition not safe, however, so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is for the locking process to pass control to the next process.  Then you can catch the exception or the file will be locked until the locking process dies or passes control.

Answer (score 0):

File `tempPath` is read by

```
System.Drawing.Image img
```

So before you delete that file, just use Dispose() method.

```
img.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap bmpCropped = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCropped);
    Rectangle rectDestination = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpCropped.Width, bmpCropped.Height);
    Rectangle rectCropArea = new Rectangle(Int32.Parse(hfX.Value), Int32.Parse(hfY.Value), Int32.Parse(hfWidth.Value), Int32.Parse(hfHeight.Value));

using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempPath)) g.DrawImage(img, rectDestination, rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```