# How can I change a file in C# after I displayed it with an WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core

I have an really annoying propblem. I am displaying a PDF File from my local Computer memory with an C#/WPF - WebBrowser. Later in my Code I want to change this PDF file, but when I try this, there comes an error message, which says the file is accessed by another process but I don't have another process that accesses the file.

**Code to display PDF C#:**

```
var documentpath = new Uri(@"C:\Users\frzrj\Desktop\test.pdf" + "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&zoom=50");
documentView.Source = documentpath;
```

**Code where I try to change the file (C#):**

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\frzrj\Desktop\test.pdf", bytes);
```

**Error when I trie to change the file:**

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\frzrj\Desktop\test.pdf' because it is being used by another process.'
```

**What I tried so far:**
I tried several things but they didn't work. I tried to use `documentView.Source = null` before editing the file, but this didn't work.
And I tried to Dispose the WebBrowser with `documentView.Dispose`. This works, but after editing the file I can't display it anymore because I get the error that I can't use disposed elements.

**Error after I used the Dispose-Methode:**

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.'
```

Has anybody an idea or a solution regardning this problem?

**thanks in advance**

Comment: if you dispose the documentView object, the system is expecting that you won't use it again, ever. If you need to display it again, you must create a new documentView.

Comment: @Martin Verjans do I have to create a new one or just initialize the documentView new

Comment: No you must create a new one. You don't know what happens when calling Dispose so basically the object becomes garbage and should not be used anymore. It is better to create a new instance.

Comment: How about unlock the pdf file before update it? like [How can I unlock a file that is locked by a process in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242882/how-can-i-unlock-a-file-that-is-locked-by-a-process-in-net)